# Python - Replacing key string inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to replace strings inside dictionary with numbers. My dictionaries are dynamically created using `from collections import defaultdict` and they look as following:

```
comp1= defaultdict(list, {'carone': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')],
                          'cartwo':[('140', '551'), ('192', '501')],
                          'carthree':[('130', '451'), ('292', '601')]}
```

**What I want:**

My aim here is to replace text string with number string and convert entire dictionary into integer to increase execution speed.

```
comp1= defaultdict(list, {'1': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')],
                          '2':[('140', '551'), ('192', '501')],
                          '3':[('130', '451'), ('292', '601')]}
```

**What I tried**

I tried two approaches:

First:

```
comp1 = {comp1:[comp1.replace("carone", "1") for k in comp1.items()]} #trying car1 first
```

Second:

```
comp1.replace("carone", "1") #replacing car1 with '1' in entire document
```

But it shows following error:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**Edit:**

The strings in my file are random text and has no number in it. They are entirely text.

Comment: Why *"replace text string with number string"* **then** convert, rather than just using the integer as a direct replacement? What *"entire document"*? What are the rules for turning e.g. `'car1'` to `'1'` (literally just whatever number it ends with? What if there are multiple keys with the same number?) Why don't you do this when *creating* the dictionary, as opposed to post-hoc? There is a lot of information missing, here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple dictionary comprehension and just get the last element of your keys :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict 
>>> 
>>> comp1= defaultdict(list, {'car1': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')],
...                           'car2':[('140', '551'), ('192', '501')],
...                           'car3':[('130', '451'), ('292', '601')]} 
... 
... 
... )
>>> 
>>> {i[-1]:j for i,j in comp1.iteritems()}
{'1': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')], '3': [('130', '451'), ('292', '601')], '2': [('140', '551'), ('192', '501')]}
>>>
```

And as a more general way which is independent of the string behind the number and the length of number, you can use regex to extract the last numbers :

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> {re.search(r'\d+$',i).group():j for i,j in comp1.iteritems()}
{'1': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')], '3': [('130', '451'), ('292', '601')], '2': [('140', '551'), ('192', '501')]}
>>>
```

Another example :

```
>>> comp1= defaultdict(list, {'car01': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')],
...                           'car25':[('140', '551'), ('192', '501')],
...                           'car123':[('130', '451'), ('292', '601')]} 
... )
>>> 
>>> {re.search(r'\d+$',i).group():j for i,j in comp1.iteritems()}
{'01': [('182', '511'), ('182', '511')], '123': [('130', '451'), ('292', '601')], '25': [('140', '551'), ('192', '501')]}
>>>
```

After your edit I must say that since dictionary items are not ordered, you can not do such thing, instead I suggest to use a `OrderedDict` using `dict.setdefault` method to simulate the behavior of `defaultdict` within an `OederedDict`. then just iterate over your items using `enumerate` and replace the keys with those index.

Comment: What about `'car10'`?

Comment: In the file that I have there are different labels and not exactly car1, car2 or car3. I just have used it to show example. Let me re-edit question.

Comment: @DhruvJ so where exactly do the numbers *come from*?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to replace all the key strings in dictionary with "1", "2" numbers when showing output. I have been told to use serial numbers which will replace corresponding labels. Sorry for misconception.

Comment: @DhruvJ *"serial numbers"* in terms of what? Dictionaries (including `defaultdict`s) are *arbitrarily ordered*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i got your point that they are arbitrarily ordered but some of my 'key' strings are fixed. These keys represent labels like labelone, labeltwo, labelthree. In above case its carone,cartwo,carthree. So this labels i need to replace with numbers.

Comment: @Kasra can you suggest solution now? I am sorry for placing labels as keys which had number inside. In my file I have labels with pure text and no numbers. You can see my re-edited file.

Comment: @DhruvJ so they *are* numbers, but in words rather than digits? Please stop wasting our time and give an example that actually represents what you're doing, and explain more clearly the purpose of it. This isn't a code-writing or debugging service, and the error messages you're receiving are perfectly clear.

Comment: @DhruvJ as jonrsharpe said its not possible to do that with `defaultdict`. you can use an `OrderedDict` at first instead of `defaultdict`